# ant builds running through maven issue

Tags: ant, maven

So I'm building a project with maven, and in this maven pom we have a reference to an ant build script. The maven pom triggers this ant build to build a project (an install of alfresco with mysql database and tomcat server packed up with it).

The issue seems to be when you try to set up a database for alfresco to use through the ant build. This is the part of the ant build.

```
<target name="createDatabase">

    <exec spawn="false" executable="${mysql.home}/bin/mysql" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-u" />
        <arg value="root" />
        <arg value="-e" />
        <arg value="source ${alfresco.home}\mysql\db_setup.sql" />
    </exec>

</target>
```

I'm getting 'unknown command '\U' sent back to me as an error on this. Of course you can install the DB manually but I want it as part of this ant script. SOmeone I work with runs this successfully on XP, but I'm getting that error on win7. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for Ant not Running in Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363119/code-for-ant-not-running-in-maven)