# Code for Ant not Running in Maven

Tags: java, r, maven, ant

This is probably the most strange thing I have ever seen in Java: The following code (that uses no external libraries) runs flawlessly using Ant (on Netbeans, on a Windows-7 Machine) :

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
  String prog = "\"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.14.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe\"";
  String[] progParams = new String[]{"C:\\Users\\pantelis\\Desktop\\SB\\MC_Sarfraz_ver5.R"};
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(prog+" "+progParams[0]);
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println(p.exitValue()==0);
  System.out.println("Done!!!"); 
}
```

and it returns the output message:

```
true
Done!!!
```

meaning that it completed smoothly. When I'm trying to run the very same code using Maven, I get no exceptions but the code finishes with:

```
false
Done!
```

and the process is never executed. This is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>MVNTest</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>MVNTest</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Update 1:** I used the following code to print any error messages generated by the process:

```
String line;
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Error in library(RDCOMClient) : there is no package called 'RDCOMClient'
Execution halted
```

This error message appears only when I run using Maven.

**Update 2:** When I run using Maven, I use JDK7. Here is the corresponding command:

```
cd C:\Users\pantelis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVNTest; 
"JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04" 
"\"C:\\Program Files\\NetBeans 7.1.2\\java\\maven\\bin\\mvn.bat\""  
"-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.mvntest.App"
"-Dexec.executable=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04\\bin\\java.exe" 
-Dexec.classpathScope=runtime process-classes 
org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec
```

**Update 3:** These are the environmental variables that I get when I run with Ant:

```
USERPROFILE -> C:\Users\pantelis
ProgramData -> C:\ProgramData
PATHEXT -> .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
Classpath -> C:\LINGO9\Lingo9_0.jar
ProgramFiles(x86) -> C:\Program Files (x86)
TEMP -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Local\Temp
SystemDrive -> C:
ProgramFiles -> C:\Program Files
Path -> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\LINGO9\;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin
HOMEDRIVE -> C:
PROCESSOR_REVISION -> 2505
USERDOMAIN -> pantelis-VAIO
ALLUSERSPROFILE -> C:\ProgramData
ProgramW6432 -> C:\Program Files
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER -> Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
SESSIONNAME -> Console
TMP -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Local\Temp
CommonProgramFiles -> C:\Program Files\Common Files
=:: -> ::\
LOGONSERVER -> \\PANTELIS-VAIO
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -> AMD64
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK -> NO
OS -> Windows_NT
HOMEPATH -> \Users\pantelis
PROCESSOR_LEVEL -> 6
CommonProgramW6432 -> C:\Program Files\Common Files
configsetroot -> C:\Windows\ConfigSetRoot
LOCALAPPDATA -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Local
COMPUTERNAME -> PANTELIS-VAIO
windir -> C:\Windows
SystemRoot -> C:\Windows
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS -> 4
USERNAME -> pantelis
PUBLIC -> C:\Users\Public
PSModulePath -> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
CommonProgramFiles(x86) -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
ComSpec -> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
APPDATA -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Roaming
```

And here are the environmental variables when I run with Maven:

```
USERPROFILE -> C:\Users\pantelis
JAVA_HOME -> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04
PROGRAMDATA -> C:\ProgramData
MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS -> "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath com.mycompany.mvntest.App" "-Dexec.executable=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe" -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec
CONFIGSETROOT -> C:\Windows\ConfigSetRoot
COMMONPROGRAMFILES -> C:\Program Files\Common Files
PROCESSOR_REVISION -> 2505
USERDOMAIN -> pantelis-VAIO
ALLUSERSPROFILE -> C:\ProgramData
PROGRAMW6432 -> C:\Program Files
SESSIONNAME -> Console
TMP -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Local\Temp
PSMODULEPATH -> C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
NB_EXEC_MAVEN_PROCESS_UUID -> b5daa24f-51dc-48ac-ad6d-820dc245b80a
M2_HOME -> C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.2\java\maven\bin\..
LOGONSERVER -> \\PANTELIS-VAIO
=:: -> ::\
PATH -> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\LINGO9\;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenVPN\bin
PROMPT -> $P$G
COMMONPROGRAMW6432 -> C:\Program Files\Common Files
PROCESSOR_LEVEL -> 6
LOCALAPPDATA -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Local
COMPUTERNAME -> PANTELIS-VAIO
CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER -> org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
USERNAME -> pantelis
APPDATA -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Roaming
WINDIR -> C:\Windows
PATHEXT -> .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROGRAMFILES(X86) -> C:\Program Files (x86)
TEMP -> C:\Users\pantelis\AppData\Local\Temp
HOMEDRIVE -> C:
SYSTEMDRIVE -> C:
=C: -> C:\Users\pantelis\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MVNTest
ERROR_CODE -> 0
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) -> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CLASSWORLDS_JAR -> "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1.2\java\maven\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar"
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER -> Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
MAVEN_JAVA_EXE -> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\java.exe"
CLASSPATH -> C:\LINGO9\Lingo9_0.jar
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE -> AMD64
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK -> NO
OS -> Windows_NT
HOMEPATH -> \Users\pantelis
COMSPEC -> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
PROGRAMFILES -> C:\Program Files
HOME -> C:\Users\pantelis
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS -> 4
PUBLIC -> C:\Users\Public
SYSTEMROOT -> C:\Windows
```

Comment: Log the exit value rather than just testing for 0. Also see if there is any output on the error stream and input stream. It's likely that you will find more info

Comment: @GuillaumePolet My code calls an R-script. I get the above error message according to which the package RDCOMClient is not found (This is an R library). Again, it is strange it runs with Ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the update, based on the error you get when running from maven, it seems some (class)path is not set up correctly: RDCOMClient seems to be related to R, so it is the setup that is used to run Rscript.exe that is the problem.

Print out the environmental variables when you are running via ant and also under maven and make a comparison to determine the source of the missing library error

Update from comments:

The problem might be related to how the project is executed from maven: `exec:exec` starts a new JVM, whereas `exec:java` runs the project in the same JVM that is running maven.

Update from comments:

Apparently, the "Compile on Save" settings in NetBeans change the maven goal from `exec:exec` to `exec:java`.  Alternatively, you can configure the pom.xml manually (see the [exec maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) page that has examples and descriptions for the two goals)

Comment: There are some differences but I can't figure out whether something is wrong therein. I'll update my question with more info.

Comment: Indeed I cannot spot anything that should make a difference (besides case sensitivity for env. var names, but I don't think that matters).  How are you executing it via ant?  You could try running it with `mvn exec:java` -- exec:exec starts a separate JVM, exec:java uses the one that is running maven.  I can't think of anytrhing else at the moment that might make a difference...

Comment: You actually helped me find the solution to the problem. It is the execution goal after all... From Netbeans, I chose the option "Compile on Save: For both application and test execution", so, after an update you deserve the green tick... Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PantelisSopasakis - Let me know if you were thinking of a different update.  I'm not sure how the netbeans setting is relevant

Comment: @Attile: When I run with "For both application blah blah" the goal changes from "exec:exec" to "run". How can I define this in my pom.xml? The solution of tweaking the "Compile On Save" property of NetBeans is IDE specific - but is still a good point to make for those using NetBeans. An amendment of the POM file is a more general result.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen with all R packages ? Or only RDCOMClient ?

I'll be very surprised if this is a Maven/Ant issue.

Reading the error stream is unnecessary. R outputs the error in a file or you can use sink("filename") to write R output to a file.

Please treat as comment.

Comment: It doesn't happen with splines for example. So I guess there is something wrong with the installation of RDCOMClient. Even a simplistic R script that contains only the line `library(RDCOMClient)` gives an error. How can I trace the error and troubleshoot it?

Comment: I guess the first thing I'd do is go to a R prompt and type library() to see the libraries i've installed correctly. I'm not on a windows machine so don't have RDCOMClient. On linux there are two locations for storing R packages and if the packages aren't stored in either of these two location, R won't have access to the library.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to specify your prog and params inside an array, and pass that array to exec.

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
  String prog = "\"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.14.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe\"";
  String[] progParams = new String[] {
     prog,
     "C:\\Users\\pantelis\\Desktop\\SB\\MC_Sarfraz_ver5.R"
  };
  Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(progParams);
  p.waitFor();
  System.out.println(p.exitValue()==0);
  System.out.println("Done!!!"); 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this version too. But bear in mind that the very same code runs flawlessly under Ant but not under Maven.

Comment: It might happen, that they use different JVMs. AFAIK, in Windows you may have java binary in System32 folder. If so, try removing it to be completely sure which JVM is used.